# Centering content of table cell in LaTeX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % to fit both tables
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second example

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering % used for centering table 

\caption{GENERAL PARAMETERS FOR THE SIMULATION} % title of Table 
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text 

\begin{tabular}{ | M{4cm} | M{4cm} | M{5cm} |} % centered columns (3 columns) 
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines 
Parameter & Value   & Observations and related works  \\ % inserts table heading 
\hline % inserts single horizontal line 

Sa & 500m x 500m   & Ar \\
\hline

\hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering % used for centering table 

\caption{GENERAL PARAMETERS FOR THE SIMULATION} % title of Table 
%\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text 

\begin{tabular}{ M{4cm} M{4cm} M{5cm} } % centered columns (3 columns) 
\toprule
Parameter & Value   & Observations and related works  \\ % inserts table heading 
\midrule
Simulation a & 500m x 500m   & Area \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Why don't you just askt egreg to remove your data? In any case, better don't remove the image, but post a different image with the confidential data removed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `\centering` in the columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % to fit both tables
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second example

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering % used for centering table 

\caption{GENERAL PARAMETERS FOR THE SIMULATION} % title of Table 
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text 

\begin{tabular}{ | M{4cm} | M{4cm} | M{5cm} |} % centered columns (3 columns) 
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines 
Parameter & Value   & Observations and related works  \\ % inserts table heading 
\hline % inserts single horizontal line 

Sa & 500m x 500m   & Ar \\
\hline

\hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering % used for centering table 

\caption{GENERAL PARAMETERS FOR THE SIMULATION} % title of Table 
%\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text 

\begin{tabular}{ M{4cm} M{4cm} M{5cm} } % centered columns (3 columns) 
\toprule
Parameter & Value   & Observations and related works  \\ % inserts table heading 
\midrule
Simulation a & 500m x 500m   & Area \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

I have added a second way to typeset the table, which I recommend.

Comment: I highly recommend the second layout as well.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary Information on edits remains available in the history. If you need something removing entirely, please use the help link at the bottom of the page to make a request to the StackExchance staff to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | m{4cm} | m{4cm} | m{5cm} |} % centered columns (4 columns)
```

You need to add the "centered justified text" parameter to your table spec. (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

Try something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c m{4cm} | c m{4cm} | c m{5cm} |} % centered columns (4 columns)
```

If that doesn't work (I don't have LaTeX on this machine), try dropping your `m{4cm}` parameter and see if that gives you what you'd like.  If you need to rescale the table after dropping the `m{4cm}` parameter, try doing [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Resize_tables).